# Nginx and If-Modified-Since/If-None-Match headers

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Anyone know how to rewrite this apache rule for Nginx?

`RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE:%{HTTP:If-Modified-Since}]`

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH:%{HTTP:If-None-Match}]

Thanks

Comment: What are those rewrite rules supposed to do and how does that differ from the behavior you're seeing with nginx?

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html Google is a useful tool.

Answer (score 2):

As I see, you are trying to pass the header HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH and HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE from nginx to fastcgi application..

Try it adding this lines in your nginx.conf file:

```
fastcgi_param HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH $http_if_none_match;
fastcgi_param HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE $http_if_modified_since;
```

After that, if you are using, for example PHP, you can get the values of the vars with either of these 2 examples:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']
$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']
```